# Sony SmartWatch2 Accelerometer sends bad values

Tags: android, sony

I have built and installed HelloSensor sample app on my Android/SmartWatch2 devices.
After commenting `//sensor.getType().getName().equals(Registration.SensorTypeValue.MAGNETIC_FIELD)`
 to avoid accelerometer values display to be scratched by magnetic field values display, I was very happy with the result: I clearly saw the expression of "SW2 acceleration - gravity" displayed on my SmartWatch (clearly seeing `~(0, 0, 9.8)` when the watch is layed down on a table, and `~(0, 9.8, 0)` when I hold the SW vertically).

My problem is that, today, whatever orientation I give to my SmartWatch, values do not change anymore => `~(0, 0, 9.8)` is always displayed, even if I hold the SW vertically.

Since it worked fine at first, I wonder if my sensor is not "broken". How can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try restarting and/or resetting your SW2?  Also you can try unpairing/repairing the watch with the phone.

If it still isn't working, not sure there is much you can do to check the sensor otherwise.  If your watch is still under warranty would suggest sending it in for repairs.